# How to email console errors in symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have configured my app to send emails on exceptions this way (`prod/monolog.yaml`):

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: grouped
            excluded_404s:
                # regex: exclude all 404 errors from the logs
                - ^/
        grouped:
            type: group
            members: [nested, deduplicated]
        deduplicated:
            type: deduplication
            handler: swift
        swift:
            type: swift_mailer
            from_email: '%admin_notifier_from%'
            to_email: '%admin_notifier_to%'
            subject: 'Error'
            level: debug
            formatter: monolog.formatter.html
            content_type: text/html
        nested:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        console:
            type:   console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine"]
```

And it works. When I throw an exception in some controller, open url for that controller I get an email with an exception. So emailing works on http level. However it does not on console level. I am using SF v4.2. I found that in recent symfony version console exception logging was added so no need to add error console listener for it. It should work on my version. Actually I see exception messages in log files. But no email. So I decided to add an error listener and log critical message (assuming it should trigger main monolog handler). So I did it. And again, I see my critical message in log file but still no email. So what wrong am I doing? I want to get exception emails on console exceptions.

I triend to replace "deduplicated" handler with "swift" one but it did not help.

Comment: I have the same issue, I've read it might have something interfering with the pool setting on swift_mailer